# How to tell python scrapy to move to the next start URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I wrote a scrapy spider that has many start_urls and extracts email adresses in these urls. The script takes ages to execute so I want to tell Scrapy to stop crawling a particular site when it finds an email and move to the next site.

**EDIT**: added code

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item
import csv
from urlparse import urlparse

from entreprise.items import MailItem

class MailSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mail"
    start_urls = []
    allowed_domains = []
    with open('scraped_data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            url = row[5].strip()
            if (url.strip() != ""):
                start_urls.append(url)
                fragments = urlparse(url).hostname.split(".")
                hostname = ".".join(len(fragments[-2]) < 4 and fragments[-3:] or fragments[-2:])
                allowed_domains.append(hostname)

    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.+')), follow=True, callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.+')), callback='parse_item')
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = []
        for mail in hxs.select('//body//text()').re(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+'):
            item = MailItem()
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['mail'] = mail
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: Could you please show the code of your spider? It'll help to answer.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to use [start_requests](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_requests) method to decide what urls to crawl next. Additionally, we'll keep track if an email was parsed for the hostname in `parsed_hostnames` class-level set.

Also, I've changed the way you get the hostname from url, using [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) now.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import csv
from urlparse import urlparse


class MailItem(Item):
    url = Field()
    mail = Field()


class MailSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mail"

    parsed_hostnames= set()
    allowed_domains = []

    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.+')), follow=True, callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.+')), callback='parse_item')
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('scraped_data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            next(reader)

            for row in reader:
                url = row[5].strip()
                if url:
                    hostname = urlparse(url).hostname
                    if hostname not in self.parsed_hostnames:
                        if hostname not in self.allowed_domains:
                            self.allowed_domains.append(hostname)
                            self.rules[0].link_extractor.allow_domains.add(hostname)
                            self.rules[1].link_extractor.allow_domains.add(hostname)

                        yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)
                    else:
                        self.allowed_domains.remove(hostname)
                        self.rules[0].link_extractor.allow_domains.remove(hostname)
                        self.rules[1].link_extractor.allow_domains.remove(hostname)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = []
        for mail in hxs.select('//body//text()').re(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+'):
            item = MailItem()
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['mail'] = mail
            items.append(item)

        hostname = urlparse(response.url).hostname
        self.parsed_hostnames.add(hostname)

        return items
```

Should work in theory. Hope that helps.

Comment: The allowed domains is not correctly set, I tested the code and the spider crawled urls in twitter which is not in the list.

Comment: Ok, this is because `allow_domains` were not set for your rules link extractors. I've edited the code - give it a try.

Comment: link_extractor.allow_domains is a set not a list, so I used add instead of append. And once an email adress is found the script does not stop crawling the current domain, so nothing really changed.

Comment: Yeah, I've already edited the answer (it's a set, right). Give it another try: now I'm removing the hostname from `allow_domains` if it's already in `parsed_hostnames`.

Comment: Not working yet :-) you can test with this url http://www.promodar.net, it should stop from rhe first request.

Comment: I think the spider only executes start_requests the first time for each start_url and then extracts the links to follow https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spiders/crawl.py

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's why I've tried to dynamically control `allow_domains` and `deny_domains` on the `SgmlLinkExtractor` itself. And it didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

I ended using process_links

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import csv
from urlparse import urlparse

class MailItem(Item):
    url = Field()
    mail = Field()

class MailSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mail"

    parsed_hostnames= set()

    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.+')), follow=True, callback='parse_item', process_links='process_links'),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.+')), callback='parse_item', process_links='process_links')
    ]

    start_urls = []
    allowed_domains = []
    with open('scraped_data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            url = row[5].strip()
            if (url.strip() != ""):
                start_urls.append(url)
                hostname = urlparse(url).hostname
                allowed_domains.append(hostname)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = []
        mails = hxs.select('//body//text()').re(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+')
        if mails:
            for mail in mails:
                item = MailItem()
                item['url'] = response.url
                item['mail'] = mail
                items.append(item)
                hostname = urlparse(response.url).hostname
                self.parsed_hostnames.add(hostname)

        return items

    def process_links(self, links):
        return [l for l in links if urlparse(l.url).hostname not in self.parsed_hostnames]
```

Comment: I found the solution thanks to your help, the trick was to look into the source code of CrawlSpider and understand how it works.